# Amazon Ec2 requirement for Magento

Tags: amazon-web-services, magento, amazon-ec2

What is the best Amazon EC2 configuration for a magento website with an average of 2500 visits per day? Currently we’re using the following configuration:

Web Server 01 - M1 Large Instance 
Web Server 02 - M1 Large Instance 
Cache Server - M1 Large Instance 
Database Server 01 - M3 Extra Large Instance 
Database Server 02 - M1 Large Instance 
Load Balancer

With the above configuration our website is slower than our previous host (Razorservers).

Here are some more data about our magento sessions: 
Our magento sessions are more than double of the number of visits Google analytics. 
Unique IPs (taken from server log) are more or less matching with Google Analytics Unique visitors.

Is this how magento behaves? or this is some configuration issue which is increasing the server load.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Questions on professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on Server Fault.

Comment: regarding "magento sessions are more than double of the number of visits Google analytics", do you run magento under two different domains in the same server?

Answer (score 0):

My recommendations are

1. Change the configuration to
   Web Server 01 - m1.xlarge 
   Web Server 02 - m1.xlarge
   Change Server 01 - M3 Extra Large Instance Database  To RDS
   Change Server 02 - M1 Large Instance Load Balancer to ELB
   Admin/Worker1 - m1.large - Memcache Cache Server/Magento Admin Server/NFS Server
2. Optimize the webservers software you can check this article for more information https://info.magento.com/Optimizing_Magento_for_Peak_Performance.html

Thanks